# Trying to make a publicly accessible AWS Cloud9 URL

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, aws-cloud9

I'm using AWS Cloud9 and it's been smooth sailing, but now I'm trying to make my URL public so that I can make HTTP requests in Postman, and I'm really struggling. I'm very much a beginner full stack developer and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Steven

I'm trying to properly follow this guide:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html

Specifically, I make it to Step 4 where it asks me to change the IP address in my code. When I change my Node JS Express app's app.listen IP address to my EC2 instance IP address, I get an error.

I think I've successfully made my EC2 instance publicly accessible and that it's just my code that is not listening correctly (those steps seemed easy to follow, but I could be wrong.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs"); 

app.get("/", function (req, res){
    res.render("helloWorld");
});


app.listen(8080, '**AWS EC2 instance IP**', function(){
    console.log("Server Has Started!");
});
```

It runs fine when I do not specify an IP address in the app.listen, but then of course I can only access the server from a different tab in the same browser. Here is what the console spits out when I run the code with the **AWS EC2 instance IP** included:

```
events.js:174

      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

      ^



Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available **AWS EC2 instance IP**:8080

    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1262:19)

    at listenInCluster (net.js:1327:12)

    at doListen (net.js:1460:7)

    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)

    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)

    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

Emitted 'error' event at:

    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1306:8)

    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]

    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: Try just `app.listen(8080, function(){` - be sure c9 is not running on that port else you need to choose another for the node app

Comment: And obviously, the error is saying `**AWS EC2 instance IP**` is not an IP address. `Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available **AWS EC2 instance IP**:8080` presuming/hopefully that's you just redacting the IP

Comment: Appreciate your input. Yes that's just me redacting the IP, I'm sure as hell not good at security yet haha. It's weird that that you're saying that in the IP error is saying that the address is not available because it should be. I have gone to AWS Console -> Security Group -> Inbound and added an Inbound Rule -> Type: Custom TCP Rule, Protocol: TCP, Port Range: 8080 - 8082, Source: 0.0.0.0/0. That should have opened it up. I have also tried app.listen(8081...) to change the port (assume you mean that c9 is running on 8080), but that hasn't fixed this either. Thoughts on that?

Comment: I used c9 from day one, did beta testing for amazon before it was public when they acquired it, received a 100+ page pdf explaining how to setup and then quickly moved away from it as amazon has ruined the user experience, in simply firing up a workspace like the old c9. I made a [bash script](https://gist.github.com/lcherone/0745b73a58fa61911edae338dd811ded) to install on a normal vps. c9 is a nodejs app, and it runs on a port, so you need to check that its not conflicting. EADDRNOTAVAIL is saying that the ip you entered does no exist, which is why I suggest not add an IP to your express.

Comment: Open your EC2 wide open and see if its the ports but most likely they doing so reverse proxy on that random generated domain that they give you, and its forwarding to wrong port

Comment: Id use, https://github.com/cdr/code-server now as c9 is dated..

Comment: helpful. will stick with this for now just because i made it this far and it's working fine. got this solved with your help - just fully opened up the ports and IP 0.0.0.0 and now it's going. thanks!

Comment: I find this guide very helpful when trying to preview my cloud9 app instance publicly.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html#app-preview-share-get-metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EC2 instances do not have their public IP bound to the IP stack. Translation from the public IP to the instance's private IP is handled automatically by the Internet Gateway.

Specifying the instance's private IP is what you actually need to do, even though it may not be intuitive that this is correct.  Or, as the guide indicates, use `0.0.0.0` which means "all interfaces."